# MYSQL select duplicated rows where 2 or 3 column values are reapeated

Tags: mysql, sql

Due to Ajax bug I end up having lots of repeated data, where the combination of 2 columns need to be unique.
I simplified the table to `name` and `surname` for this question.

Imagine in Table `users` how can I get the `id` where `name` + `surname` is duplicated.
I  have attached a picture.

[image: Table users]

Comment: Use `Distinct` or `Group By`

Comment: Thank you. I did with DISTINCT it didn't work, i will try with Group By.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, surname FROM users t1 WHERE 
  EXISTS(SELECT id FROM users t2 
            WHERE t1.id <> t2.id AND 
                  t1.name = t2.name AND 
                  t1.surname = t2.surname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Id from  users u inner join 
(SELECT  name,surname,count(*) cnt FROM  users GROUP BY name,surname 
HAVING cnt >1) dup on dup.name = u.name and u.surname = dup.surname
```

see  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/378e5/1)